# Solving an equation that contains commutators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, commutator, density-operator

I am reading [Luttinger's theory of thermal transport coefficients (1964)](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRev.135.A1505). It has the following equation
$$[H,f] -isf = [\rho,F].\tag{1.7}$$
$H$ and $\rho$ is Hamiltonian and the density matrix of the unperturbed system, respectively. The perturbation is $Fe^{st}$, $s$ a small positive number and $f$ is change in density matrix due to perturbation i.e. total density matrix $$\equiv \rho_T = \rho + fe^{st}\tag{1.6}.$$

The goal is to solve the above given equation for $f$. The article says "... by going to the representation where $H$ is diagonal, the solution of the above equation is given by"
$$f = i\int_0^\infty dt e^{-st} e^{-iHt}[\rho,F]e^{iHt}.\tag{1.9-10}$$

I don't understand how do we arrive at this solution. Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the Energy diagonal representation
$$
\langle n |([H,f]-isf)|m \rangle = ((E_n-E_m)-isf)\langle n|f|m \rangle
$$
Now take the same matrix element of the left- and right-hand sides of the  claimed answer :
$$
\langle n |f |m \rangle= i\int_0^\infty dt e^{-st}  e^{-i(E_n-E_m)t} \langle n |[\rho, F]| m\rangle\\
= \frac{i}{i(E_n-E_m)+s } \langle n |[\rho, F]| m\rangle. 
$$
In doing the integral over $t$ I assume that the commutator $[\rho, F]$ is independent of $t$.
If I got the signs right, this shows that $f$ satisfies the required equation.